# How to compile html outside of ng-app scope after partial update

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have a user-control that uses `anguar.js` and declares a `div` with `ng-app` somewhere inside.
The other part of the system doesn't use `angular.js` and doesn't even reference it.

Now, the problem is that after partial update of html (using update-panel, for instance) I need to recompile it (because it's injected into DOM) and I cannot technically do this, as far as whole html together with `ng-app` declaration is being replaced.

And I do not have access to `$compile` service (okay, I can get it using `$injector`, but where do I get the `$scope`?)

```
function AfterPartialUpdate(containerElement) {
    var injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    injector.invoke(function($compile) {
        $compile(containerElement)( ???need scope, which is lost );
    });
};
```

I can store the scope at the moment of initial page-load in some global variable.
But recompiling using the same scope results in incremental increase of `$$watchers` collection and other unwanted side-effects...

I guess there should be a way to force angular to execute all that same javascript it executes during intial page-load, i.e. create modules, traverse html, instantiate controllers, etc?

Comment: injector also provides you with $rootScope service. Try this     injector.invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        $compile(containerElement)($rootScope);
    });

Comment: but I guess $rootScope is not the one I actually need? because I need child scope of my controller

Comment: You said that you replace whole ng-app ?

Comment: yes. I tried to use `$compile(containerElement)($rootScope)`, and it's done without errors, but when I do `containerElement.scope()` I get `undefined` and resulting html is incorrect (for instance I have `<div ng-if='dataSource != null'`, obviously `dataSource` is null, so contents are empty)

Comment: Can you post your html and other relevant angularjs code?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets, I'll give one more try to figure things out (using $rootScope), maybe I missed somthing, then I'll post simplified html/js

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets, I've re-tested and figured out I had been using the wrong `containerElement` (child div of ng-controller div instead of the latter). The solution with `$injector` + `$rootScope` works! Can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injector provides you with $rootScope service. Try to use it to compile the element:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
injector.invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    $compile(containerElement)($rootScope);
});
```

Comment: I've found one more interesting thing - in order for bindings to apply after you compile template you need to call $rootScope.$apply();. If you don't do that then bindings won't be resolved until any changes (for example user input). Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fpns8/4/

Comment: that's true, you should always call `$apply` after manual compilation in order to resolve current data-binding.